# Malloc has junk for C string?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, so feel free to correct mistakes.

I have some code that somewhat goes like this:

```
// some variables declared here like int array_size
char* cmd = (char*)malloc(array_size*sizeof(char));
for(;;){
    // code here sets cmd to some string
    free(cmd);
    array_size = 10;
    cmd = (char*)malloc(array_size*sizeof(char));
    // print 1
    printf(cmd);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(cmd));

    // repeat above for some time and then break

}
```

So I do the loop for a while and see what it prints.  What I expected was every time the string would be empty and the length would be 0.  However, that is not the case.  Apparently sometimes malloc gets memory with junk and prints that out and that memory with junk has a length != 0.  So I was thinking about solving this by setting all char in a new char string to '\0' when malloc returns; however, I'm pretty sure I just did something wrong.  Why is it even after I free the string and do a whole new malloc that my string comes with junk unlike the first malloc?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some (such as myself) consider the casting of the return value of `malloc` to be bad style, and more generally consider `type *t = malloc(n * sizeof *t);` more future-proof than `type *t = (type *)malloc(n * sizeof(type));` because, if you have to change `type`, the first line only requires one change, while the second requires 3 (and for `realloc` calls, it's no changes vs. 2 changes).

Comment: It's not just bad style, it hides errors that would otherwise be detected, specifically forgetting to include the header containing the malloc prototype, damn near fatal in environments where ints are different widths to pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`malloc` just allocated the memory and nothing more. It has no promises about what is in the memory. Specifically, it does not initialize memory. If you want allocated memory to be zeroed out, you can either do it manually with `memset` or simply call `calloc` (which is essentially `malloc` with zeroing out of memory).

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` does not initialise the memory. You are just lucky the first time around.

Also if it is *junk* and contains a % symbol you are going to have other problems.

Comment: +1 for the other problems part.  It would be better if you pointed out the correct way of dealing with it, namely `printf("%s\n", cmd);`.

Comment: @jonathan - Bit of a moot point methinks as the code is errorenous. Also the `string` might not be null terminated!

Comment: It avoids a few problems, but is certainly no cure-all.  You're right, the string will likely not be null terminated in the allocated length.  However, even if you assumed an even distribution of the byte values, you would expect to encounter a zero byte fairly soon.  In practice, though, zero bytes typically appear a lot more often than other bytes in the primordial soup of the typical program's memory space.

Answer (score 0):

No you did nothing wrong - malloc does not guarantee the memory will be set to 0, only that it belongs to your process. 
In general setting newly allocated memory to zero in unneeded so in C it is never explicitly cleared which would take several clock cycles. 
There is a rather convenient method 'memset' to set it if you need

Comment: One could argue that what he did wrong was assume that the memory allocated would be cleanly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your code segment has, at a minimum, the following problems.

1. You don't ever need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` - it's *always* one.
2. You cast the return value of `malloc`. This can hide errors that would otherwise be detected, such as if you forget to include the header with the `malloc` prototype (so it assumes `int` return code).
3. `malloc` is not required to do anything with the memory it gives you, nor will it necessarily give you the same block you just freed. You can initialise it to an empty string with a simple `*cmd = '\0';` after *every* `malloc` if that's what you need.
4. `printf (cmd)` is dangerous if you don't know what `cmd` contains. If it has a format specifier character (`%`), you will get into trouble. A better way is `printf ("%s", cmd)`.

Comment: Even the `printf("%s", cmd);` can have problems as cmd has undefined contents and might not be null terminated.

Comment: @Ed, I'd consider that covered by point 3 and/or "if you don't know what cmd contains".